# Pipe in magrittr package is not working for function load()

Tags: r, magrittr

It seem `%>%` in the *magrittr* package is not working for the function `load()`. This is my minimal example to reproduce my question.

```
## Create two example variables and save to tempdir()
a <- 1
b <- 1

save(list = ls(), file = file.path(tempdir(), 'tmp.RData'))

## Remove all variables and load into global environment
# rm(list = ls())

load(file.path(tempdir(), 'tmp.RData'))
ls()
# [1] "a" "b"

# Write the same code with pipe "%>%", but not variable is loaded
# rm(list =ls())
library(magrittr)

tempdir() %>% file.path('tmp.RData') %>% load
ls()
# character(0)
```

I don't understand why the pipe is not working for `load()`. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: It's not usually good form to include `rm(list=ls())` in example code, so people don't destroy their working data unintentionally.

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks for your editing. I normally open a new session to test example codes from stackoverflow and others.

Comment: that's probably smart. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `envir` argument in `load()` needs to be specified as either `globalenv()`  or `parent.frame(3)`.

```
# in a fresh R session ...
a <- 1
b <- 1
save(list = ls(), file = file.path(tempdir(), 'tmp.RData'))

# in another fresh session ...
ls()
# character(0)
tempdir() %>% file.path("tmp.RData") %>% load(envir = globalenv())
ls()
# [1] "a" "b"
```

The following also works:

```
tempdir() %>% file.path("tmp.RData") %>% load(envir = parent.frame(3))
```

I'll try to explain why.  When you call `load()` from any environment, the function loads the new objects in the parent environment.

Now, the global environment `globalenv()` is your R workspace.  So, if you call load from the global environment (i.e. the workspace) everything works as you expect.  Visualise this:

- Global environment

  - `load()`

However, if you call `load()` from inside a function, then you've inserted an environment in between load and the global environment.  Visualise this:

- Global environment

  - function

    - `load()`

This is exactly what happens when you put `%>%` into the mix:

- Global environment

  - `%>%`

    - `load()`

There are two solutions for resolving this.  Either explicitly point to `globalenv()` or walk 3 steps up the chain to the global environment using `parent.frame(3)`.

---

**Note:**  There was an [issue reported on GitHub](https://github.com/smbache/magrittr/issues/38) for this.  Not sure what the resolution was, or if there is one yet.  The issue was just reported in September.

Many thanks to @Andrie for improving this explanation.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It is working for global environment, but still need to fix it when calling "load" in a function.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. For my digging, pipe truly evaluate the function load and load all variable into the new environment. But the returned values are invisible (visible=FALSE), so pipe return an invisible result (invisible(result[["value"]])). Not sure how to fix it.

Comment: See detail in the comment of github: https://github.com/smbache/magrittr/issues/38

Comment: @Andrie Thanks for your explanation. It does make sense to me. And parent.frame(3) still works when calling load inside custom functions.

Comment: @Bangyou Just note that `parent.frame(3)` will only work if the global environment is 3 frames up the chain.  If you embed the function in another, then that number is going to increment.

Comment: @Andrie I have test it inside functions and it works. See my testing codes here: http://pastebin.com/UbXt3CnJ

Comment: @Bangyou Be careful.  It's not a good idea.  It's better to explicitly specify the environment you want.

Comment: @Andrie Yes it is a bad idea. I just test the idea.