# Optimize R chains (magrittr)

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, magrittr

I would like to pipe (chain) magrittr object into loop. How can I do this?
I will use dummy operations/data as an example:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

# Dummy data modification
d <- mtcars %>%
    setDT() %>%
    .[, cylSQ := sqrt(cyl)] %>%
    .[, carb3 := carb^3]
# Dummy loop
res <- list()
for(i in unique(d$gear)) {
    res[[i]] <- d[gear == i] %>%
        .[, lm(cylSQ ~ mpg + carb3 * wt)] %>%
        .$fitted.values
}
```

Is it possible not to create object `d` and to pipe it directly to loop? For example:

```
for(i in unique(.$gear)) {
    res[[i]] <- .[gear == i] %>%
    ...
}
```

**Edit:** I don't want to replace loop with `data.table` or `dplyr`, just curious about piping.

Comment: I might be wrong, is not the reason there is `purrr` package?

Comment: @zx8754 I haven't heard about it before, don't know it is what I am looking for, but still it seems very good and worth looking at. Thanks for good suggestion!

Comment: `mtcars %>% setDT` goes against the dplyr grammar/philosophy of not modifying input, fyi.

Comment: @Frank doesn't `%>%` do copy? I tried `setDT(mtcars)` and it throws error, as expected.

Comment: @jangorecki Yeah, that's what I thought would happen but somehow the pipe overrides the lock, so `mtcars %>%
    setDT` actually alters `mtcars`.

Comment: [Don't pipe in a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38882226/817778)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of sketchy work around, but you can use the exposition operator in the `magrittr` package `%$%`.

I.e.:

```
mtcars %>% 
  filter(hp > 1) %$%
  for(i in 1:ncol(.)) {
    print(.[1,i])
  }

[1] 21
[1] 6
[1] 160
[1] 110
[1] 3.9
[1] 2.62
[1] 16.46
[1] 0
[1] 1
[1] 4
[1] 4
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't you mind using `dplyr` instead of `data.table` here? If not, try this:

```
library(dplyr)
d <- mtcars %>% 
    mutate(cylSQ = sqrt(cyl), carb3 = carb^3) %>% 
    group_by(gear) %>% 
    do(fitted.values = lm(cylSQ ~ mpg + carb3 * wt, data = .)[["fitted.values"]])
```

Comment: Looks really nice.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not magrittr practitioner so it could probably be improved, but at least works, and should be efficient.

```
as.data.table(mtcars
              )[, cylSQ := sqrt(cyl)
                ][, carb3 := carb^3
                  ][, lm(cylSQ ~ mpg + carb3 * wt)$fitted.values, by=gear
                    ] %>% 
    split(by = "gear", keep.by = FALSE) %>% 
    lapply(unlist) %>% 
    lapply(unname) -> res
```

Due to new `split.data.table` it requires data.table in 1.9.7, see [installation wiki](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) for details how to install on various platforms.