# What environment should I use with %>% mget

Tags: r, magrittr

I'm collecting some objects by name to save as a list in an RDS:

```
A = 1
B = 2
mget(c("A","B"))
```

If I want to pipe...

```
library(magrittr)
c("A","B") %>% mget                    # nope
c("A","B") %>% mget(env = globalenv()) # ok
```

But if I'm working inside some environment and I don't want to retype its name...

```
e = new.env()
e$a = 1
e$b = 2
with(e, {
  # do some stuff, then...
  c("a","b") %>% mget
})
```

I'm assuming I should type `%>% mget(env = something)`,  but can't figure out what (apart from `e`).

Comment: I'm asking more out of curiosity than an immediate need for this...

Comment: Heh, so after reading Richard Scriven's answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/27054476/ I tried every parent.frame(n) and found that n=6 works. Go figure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably get away with `parent.env(environment())`, as in

```
with( e, { c("a","b") %>% mget(env=parent.env(environment())) })
```

Comment: Thanks! New variation: Can I make something like this work? `mmget <- mget;
formals(mmget)[["envir"]] <- quote(parent.env(environment()));
with(e, c("a","b") %>% mmget)` or is that too stupid an idea?

Comment: Anyway, if you don't know or prefer not to extend the answer to cover that, I can post a new question. I can't figure it out beyond `mmget <- mget;
formals(mmget)[["envir"]] <- quote(parent.frame(7));
with(e, c("a","b") %>% mmget)` which looks incredibly fragile.

Comment: @Frank yea that sounds tricky.  If you define `mmet` there, its enclosing environment would be the global, so its parent would be the base.  The evaluation of `environment` needs to be delayed until its inside of the pipes environment wrapper.