# Pipe in magrittr package is not working for function rm()

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

```
x = 10
rm(x) # removed x from the environment

x = 10
x %>% rm() # Doesn't remove the variable x
```

1) Why doesn't pipe technique remove the variable?
2) How do I alternatively use pipe and rm() to remove a variable?

Footnote: This question is perhaps similar to [Pipe in magrittr package is not working for function load()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27053935/pipe-in-magrittr-package-is-not-working-for-function-load)

Comment: Like all the operations in `dplyr` you need to assign the value back to the original variable if you want to see it's effect. Do `x <- x %>% rm()` and then print `x`.

Comment: Kind of like doing `function(x) {rm(x)}` although I don't think that explains why the dlpyr-assigning the value back to the object succeeds.

Comment: `rm` requires the variable name in some fashion, but the way pipelines are evaluated, `x` is already retrieved by the time it gets passed to `rm`, so the name is not available on the right-hand side of the pipe. The value is stored as a temporary variable, but the original name is discarded after it's used. Thus, the only way to pipe into `rm` is to quote the variable name in some fashion, and the quoting has to be in the same call as the variable, e.g. `x <- 10; quote(x) %>% purrr::invoke(rm, ., .env = .GlobalEnv)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `%<>%` operator for assigning the value to `NULL`

```
x %<>% 
   rm()
```

In the pipe, we are getting the value instead of the object.  So, by using the `%<>%` i.e. in place compound assignment operator, the value of 'x' is assigned to NULL

```
x
#NULL
```

---

If we need the object to be removed, pass it as  `character` string, feed it to the `list` argument of `rm` which takes a `character` object and then specify the `environment`

```
x <- 10
"x" %>% 
    rm(list = ., envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

When we call 'x'

```
x
```

> Error: object 'x' not found

The reason why the `...` doesn't work is that the object `.` is not evaluated within the `rm`

```
x <- 10
"x" %>%
    rm(envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

> Warning message: In rm(., envir = .GlobalEnv) : object '.' not found

---

Another option is using `do.call`

```
x <- 10
"x" %>%
   list(., envir = .GlobalEnv) %>% 
   do.call(rm, .)
x
```

> Error: object 'x' not found

Comment: What is the name of that operator?

Comment: @Amar It is a compound assignment operator